# Symfony form NumberType: This value is not valid

Tags: forms, symfony, silex

I have a NumberType field:

```
    ->add('numero', NumberType::class, [
        'required' => true,
        'attr' => [
            'placeholder' => "Numéro de la carte",
        ],
        'constraints' => [
            new Assert\NotBlank(['message' => "Ce champ est obligatoire."]),
            new Assert\Regex([
                'pattern' => '/^[0-9]{16}$/',
                'match'   => true,
                'message' => 'Le numéro de la carte doit être une suite de 16 chiffres.',
            ]),
        ]
    ])
```

Required as my regex said, a suite of 16 numbers. But I always got the "This value is not valid" message for more than 7 numbers. I don't know why.

Comment: which numbers have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You should change NumberType::class to TextType:class and it should work just fine